# How to include additional conditions inside a main WHERE clause? (like an if inside a higher-level if conditional)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `aus_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` with the following schema:

[image: aus_woocommerce_order_itemmeta]

How can I create a query that yields the following logic?

```sql
SELECT * FROM aus_woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE order_item_id  = 660
    /* And only from those items, the ones with order_item_id = 660
    SELECT the rows that meet any of the following conditions: */
meta_key LIKE "%bebida caliente%"
meta_key LIKE "%elige%"
meta_key  LIKE "%agregar%";
```

This is my current query:

```sql
SELECT order_item_id, meta_key, meta_value 
FROM aus_woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE order_item_id  = 660
AND meta_key LIKE "%bebida caliente%"
OR meta_key LIKE "%elige%"
OR meta_key  LIKE "%agregar%";
```

But obviously, the `OR` statements are on the same level as the first `WHERE` condition, so it's returning everything, regardless of its `order_item_id`.

Comment: parentheses, like you would in most languages where you want to mix and and or operators and don't like the precedence rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just wrap the or statement in a parenthesis like this.**

```
SELECT order_item_id, meta_key, meta_value 
FROM aus_woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE order_item_id  = 660
AND (meta_key LIKE "%bebida caliente%"
OR meta_key LIKE "%elige%"
OR meta_key  LIKE "%agregar%");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: You are welcome :)